# Preferred method to format logs from the Couchbase tracing package?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

By default, all the logs from the tracing package (such as **com.couchbase.tracing][OverThresholdRequestsRecordedEvent**) are JSON documents  such as

```
{
  "kv": {
    "top_requests": [
      {
        "operation_name": "get",
        "last_dispatch_duration_us": 113274,
        "last_remote_socket": "xxx:11210",
        "last_local_id": "78C03F4700000001/000000008AA7BA2A",
        "last_local_socket": "xxx:49908",
        "total_dispatch_duration_us": 113274,
        "total_server_duration_us": 19,
        "operation_id": "0x152f3",
        "timeout_ms": 250,
        "last_server_duration_us": 19,
        "total_duration_us": 113388
      }
    ],
    "total_count": 1
  }
}
```

As I use Splunk to process my logs, It is highly preferred to have the logs with the format **field=value**

I am aware that Splunk can process JSON documents at runtime, but that adds overhead at query time

Is there any recommended approach to do this?

As an initial approach, I was thinking to subscribe to the Couchbase Event bus and format it there. But I am not sure if that's the best approach

```
clusterEnvironment.eventBus().subscribe(e-> {

            if (e instanceof OverThresholdRequestsRecordedEvent){
                // format
            }

        });
```

Comment: Subscribing to the event bus sounds like a good solution. The Couchbase SDK has a [`Context.ExportFormat`](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-jvm-clients/blob/master/core-io/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/core/cnc/Context.java#L51) interface that determines how the events are logged, but [`LoggingEventConsumer` always uses JSON format](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-jvm-clients/blob/master/core-io/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/core/cnc/LoggingEventConsumer.java#L129).